# How to display 2 months with datepicker yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I need to display 2 months using datepicker here

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'date_debut')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::class, [
    'language' => 'fr',
    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-control']
]) ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _only 2 months_?

Comment: I need to display a double calendar to specify end_date and start_date

Comment: if you need a double calendar you need 2 inputs one for start_date and one for end_date

Comment: are you trying to select a date range by clicking on the input

Comment: I search about how can I click in only one input then two calendars appear.
The start date will be saved in the first input and the second in the other one

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two inputs. The first one will be for the start date and the second one will be for the end date. If you happen to need to open both inputs at once when you click on one of them, you should trigger the event on the other one. I.e. `start_date.onclick` should trigger `end_date.onclick` and the vice versa.